# Scala reflection with parameterized types

Tags: scala

I've written the following function to check whether a given singleton class implements a trait.

```
/** Given a singleton class, returns singleton object if cls implements T.                                                 
 * Else returns None. */
 def maybeMakeSingletonObj[T: ClassManifest](cls: Class[_]): Option[T] = {
   try {
     val m = classManifest[T]
     val obj = cls.getField("MODULE$").get(m.erasure).asInstanceOf[AnyRef]

     if (Manifest.singleType(obj) <:< m) Some(obj.asInstanceOf[T])
     else None
   } catch {
     case e: Exception => None
   }
 }
```

This code works fine on the following example:

```
trait A
object B extends A

assert(maybeMakeSingletonObj[A](B.getClass()) === Some(B))
```

However, fails on the following example:

```
trait A[T, R]
object B extends A[Int, Int]

assert(maybeMakeSingletonObj[A[_,_]](B.getClass()) === Some(B))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It would help if you would describe the failure, or at least include self-contained code.

Comment: The code is self-contained. The failure is simply that maybeMakeSingletonObj isn't returning Some(B) in the second case-- it's returning None. The manifest check isn't working as it does in the first case. Also, it's returning None not due to an Exception being thrown, but because of the manifest check.

Comment: I wonder if this is due to erasure? My understanding is that parameterizations aren't supposed to survive compilation -- ie it isn't possible to see them with reflection. Could be wrong though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.Manifest): "The type-relation operators <:< and =:= should be considered approximations only, as there are numerous aspects of type conformance which are not yet adequately represented in manifests." Apparently, this is one such case.